# Meaning of "on aura l’air malin"

Tags: sens, expressions, ironie

> En outre, j’ai remarqué que cette initiative avait remis pour moi une forme de sens dans des conférences parfois un peu trop orientées « business ».  Le business, c’est chouette, mais **on aura l’air malin** si la Terre n’a plus d’arbre…
>
> Bref, tout ceci m’a poussé à chercher un moyen de faire beaucoup mieux que ces quelques milliers d’arbres que je pouvais planter seul dans mon coin. (https://nicolasberetti.com/2017/10/26/des-conferences-qui-plantent-des-arbres-speaker4earth/)

I think this is an ironic expression, but what does it exactly mean? Is it always used ironically?

Answer (score 3):

It means 'we will look stupid'. It is always used ironically.

Answer (score 1):

***[Malin](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/malin)*** is an interesting word as it started to be negative only (*qui fait [du/le/∅] mal*, "doing evil") but evolved to a shifted alternate positive meaning ("being astute, smart").

As in you question, it is also often used in antiphrasis, so both of these sentences are negatives, although with a slight difference:

> Il a l'air malin.
>
> Il n'a pas l'air malin.

In the first case, the person has just done something or is affected by something that just happen, and is looking stupid. This is a temporary state.

In the second one, the person just doesn't look smart. This is more of a permanent state. If you are familiar with Spanish, that's a typical use case of *estar/ser* difference.

Depending on the context, *il a l'air malin* might also be used a positive way (he looks smart).

Note also that *malin* has two feminines, *maligne* and *maline*. The second one is prevailing nowadays, especially when "smart" is the expected meaning.

Finally, you migh read either of these three sentences:

> *Elle a l'air maligne.* (old fashioned)
>
> *Elle a l'air maline.* (usual)
>
> *Elle a l'air malin.*

In both first case, *mali(g)ne* applies to *elle* (*elle a l'air d'être maline*, "she looks smart/stupid*)

In the last one, *malin* applis to *air* (look), which is a masculine word ("she has a smart/stupid look").

Answer (score 0):

While "*On aura l’air malin si ...*" does translate as "*we will look smart/stupid if ...*", the fundamental idea that this invariably ironic turn of phrase conveys in this context is rather:

> We are **on** **a fool's errand** if we're looking to expand our business without any concern for the environment.

... with "*a fool's errand*" referring to "*a pointless undertaking*".

Comment: It doesn't translate *literally* to *we will look stupid*, more like *we'll look clever*, as in *we'll look pretty clever when there are no trees left*.

Comment: @Minty What you said ! Just happened to copy the phrase in Jurgen's answer without thinking twice.

Comment: :-) I do that sort of thing all the time. I see you've edited it now anyway.